# Change color in SQlite based application

Tags: iphone, python, objective-c, sqlite

let me explain this clearly: i'm decide to learn about how to store my data with SQLite, and i decide to download sample code and examine it.

So, i have a .csv file with data, when my program launch, first thing user see is rows of elements. (Its like when you enter "Contacts" in your iPhone, just rows with names on it). When user tap an element, next view display data about it (not really matter what data is, there is a xib controller and its easy to manage).

My question is - how to change color of rows? I don't want it to be "standard white" color, maybe some color i want to import (or default colors, but not just white).

This sqlite3 file was created using .csv file, sqlite command tab (terminal), and python. Then imported to application in Xcode.

Please help me!

Comment: The database and the display are totally unrelated.  The way in which your tableview gets populated has no effect on the colour of rows.

Comment: Your question is not quite clear,which component's color you wanted to change is it a UITableView's row color or anything else..?

Comment: i mean row color (not text color).

Comment: As Soviut said, the display of your data is in no way related to the data itself. Neither row color nor text color. The database just contains the text, no information about how to display that text.

Answer (score 0):

Color display is controlled by your "sample code". If you really want to change the colors you'll need to ask more specifically in case someone else has seen it. To do it yourself, you need to dig into the source (or in its documentation), find where and how it sets the colors, and change it. A possible short-cut would be to search for common color names using an all-file search (if your IDE offers it, or using grep if you're developing on linux/osx). This might lead you to the places where colors are defined.

But if your goal is to learn SQL, my advice would be not to waste your time on the application. Ignore the ugly colors and move on to a different environment as soon as you get the chance.

Comment: thanks you very much, yes my goal is learn SQL, but i don't want things to look ugly. I find very easy way to do it, in ViewDidLoad just typed: self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sky.png"]];

Comment: Good, glad to hear it. You solved the problem, and this is the solution, but we your readers still don't know what problem you solved: You changed the display color in what sample application or framework? Your question had nothing to do with sqlite3, as everyone told you.

Comment: Okay, I'm just grab some other guy example and study it, trying to get explanation about sqlite work, sorry for misunderstanding, I'm new in all that stuff :) I thought maybe it some kind of string in python script, but it was simple. This simple line of code just change every row in array when it display it.